# Cannot close popup login MSAL with React

Tags: reactjs, azure, popup, token, msal.js

im trying to login using MSAL with react.
I make code for recover the token generated by MSAL (for later use it with fetch methods); in the process i use the method **loginPopup()** for open a popup where the user must put his access account data from Microsoft, when finalized this popup must be closed automatically but it doesnt; the popup remain and redirect inside my default page:
[image]

I dont know if this is a bug or if i need another configuration; the version of MSAL is:
**"@azure/msal-browser": "^3.1.0"**.

My configuration is type:

```
const MsalConfig = {
 auth: {
  clientId: "THIS_IS_SECRET",
  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/THIS_IS_SECRET",
  redirectUri: "https://myappservicetests.azurewebsites.net/", // Cambia esto a tu URI de redirección
},
cache: {
  cacheLocation: "localStorage",
  storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
},
system: {   
    loggerOptions: {    
        loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {  
            if (containsPii) {      
                return;     
            }       
            switch (level) {        
                case LogLevel.Error:        
                    console.error(message);     
                    return;     
                case LogLevel.Warning:      
                    console.warn(message);      
                    return;     
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
};
```

My get token code is:

```
const GetLoginToken = async () => {
 const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(ClientSettings.MsalConfig);
 await msalInstance.initialize();

 const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["user.read"], 
 };

 const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

 if (accounts.length > 0) {
    const accessTokenRequest = {
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        account: accounts[0], 
    };

    try {
        const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest);
        localStorage.setItem("tokenAZWebAppTest", tokenResponse.accessToken);
        return tokenResponse.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle token acquisition error
        console.error("Error during silent token acquisition:", error);
    }
} else {

    try {
        msalInstance.addEventCallback((event) => {
            if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
                window.close();
            }
        });

        const response = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
        console.log("Login response: ", response);

        if (response.account) {
            const tokenRequest = {
                scopes: ["user.read"],
                account: response.account,
            };

            const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
            localStorage.setItem("tokenAZWebAppTest", tokenResponse.accessToken);
            return tokenResponse.accessToken;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during login:", error);
    }
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: i had to use another way because for IE and Safari, the method loginPopup() can generate bugs and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use another way, i found than the method **loginPopup()** for IE and Safari can generates bugs and errors; for that, i use msal-react directly using a unique instance and using **Redirect**:

I use the documentation on [Msal React examples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/getting-started.md)

In my index.js use **MsalProvider** :

```
const pca = new PublicClientApplication(ClientSettings.MsalConfig);

root.render(
 <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
  <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
 </MsalProvider>
);
```

For my page components i used the **methods of library**:

```
export default function Post() {
  const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();
  const account = useAccount(accounts[0] || {});

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
       if(account){
         await LoadList();
       }
   })();
  }, [account, instance]);

  const LoadList = async () => {
    let list = await PostService.GetListPosts(instance);
      if (list !== null) setPosts(list);
  };

  return(
        <MsalAuthenticationTemplate
          interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect}
          authenticationRequest={ClientSettings.LoginRequest}
         >
             <div>...</div>
         </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
  );
```

And with the instance i can get the token in another methods of another files:

```
const acquireAccessToken = async (msalInstance) => {
  const activeAccount = msalInstance.getActiveAccount(); // This will only return a non-null value if you have logic somewhere else that calls the setActiveAccount API
  const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

  if (!activeAccount && accounts.length === 0) {
    alert("Users not signed in.")
    return null;
  }
  const request = {
    scopes: ["User.Read"],
    account: activeAccount || accounts[0]
  };

  const authResult = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);

  return authResult.accessToken
 }
```